# Failling importing EcoInvent 3.3

Tags: python, database, spyder

I am having trouble to import ecoinvent 3.3 in brightway (Spyder (Python 3.6, Last version of BW2, Windows 64). I am following the seminar2017, everythings works fine until the LCI sub chapter where I am actually stacked because I cannot import ecoinvent 3.3, I have access to the ecoinvent (even 3.5) but I just want to follow the seminar since I cannot fix the 2.2 unlinked exchanges problem.

I have downloaded and imported the file ecoinvent 3.3_cutoff_ecoSpold02 and placed it in a folder that I am pointing to following the code provided by the developers/or the seminar:

```
fpei33 = r'C:\Users\gaylordb\Documents\Golf\OiErgasiesMou\ei33'

if 'ecoinvent 3.3 cutoff' in bw.databases:
    print("Database has already been imported")
else:
    ei33 = bw.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(fpei33, 'ecoinvent 3.3 cutoff')
    ei33.apply_strategies()
    ei33.statistics()
```

The results is:

```
Extracting XML data from 0 datasets
Extracted 0 datasets in 0.18 seconds
Applying strategy: normalize_units
Applying strategy: update_ecoinvent_locations
Applying strategy: remove_zero_amount_coproducts
Applying strategy: remove_zero_amount_inputs_with_no_activity
Applying strategy: remove_unnamed_parameters
Applying strategy: es2_assign_only_product_with_amount_as_reference_product
Applying strategy: assign_single_product_as_activity
Applying strategy: create_composite_code
Applying strategy: drop_unspecified_subcategories
Applying strategy: fix_ecoinvent_flows_pre35
Applying strategy: drop_temporary_outdated_biosphere_flows
Applying strategy: link_biosphere_by_flow_uuid
Applying strategy: link_internal_technosphere_by_composite_code
Applying strategy: delete_exchanges_missing_activity
Applying strategy: delete_ghost_exchanges
Applying strategy: remove_uncertainty_from_negative_loss_exchanges
Applying strategy: fix_unreasonably_high_lognormal_uncertainties
Applying strategy: set_lognormal_loc_value
Applying strategy: convert_activity_parameters_to_list
Applied 19 strategies in 0.02 seconds
0 datasets
0 exchanges
0 unlinked exchanges
```

If I then pursue with writing the database, I get the following:

> ei33.write_database() Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       ei33.write_database()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\gaylordb\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\mylcaenv\lib\site-packages\bw2io\importers\base_lci.py",
>   line 207, in write_database
>       raise WrongDatabase(error)
>
> WrongDatabase: Activity database must be ecoinvent 3.3 cutoff, but
>   set() was also found

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your data or your path - see the line `Extracted 0 datasets in 0.18 seconds`. Maybe you didn't extract the 7z archive?